# Java Unparseable date Exception yyyyMMdd h:m a

Tags: java, timestamp

I have this `20160407 4:30 pm` data time string and I want to transfer it to timestamp.

```
Timestamp timestamp = null;
try {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd h:m a");
  //SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
  Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("20160407 4:30 pm");
  timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I got error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20160407 4:30 pm "
```

Comment: Works fine here, with Java 8. What is your locale? Maybe `pm` is not how you say `pm` in your locale. Try with Locale.US instead of your default locale. Also, post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet Agree with you. Should check the local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently in US and your code runs fine if I don't specify a locale. However, the same exception raised when I explicitly changed my locale to China as in Chinese we use '下午' for 'pm' and '上午' for 'am', so if you change 'pm' to '下午' in my code, it will work then.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CHINA;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd h:m a", locale);

Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("20160407 4:30 pm");
```

So please check what your default locale is by `Locale locale = Locale.getDefault()`.

Also, I would suggest you use the newer Java date and time API too.

Comment: The formatter class will use the pattern you specify, even if that's not the locale default.  I see no reason to vote this up.

Comment: @duffymo yeah, it will and then in this locale it might fail, that's why there is an error. You can take a look at: [Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @duffymo The error occurred when parsing since he is trying to parse a string as a date, not formating a `Date` object to string

Comment: @duffymo in China, people don't use the same language as in the US. In particular, I doubt "pm" is spelt "pm" in Chinese. So, in Chinese, "pm" is not parsable. As simple as that.